# Why does sensitivity of nmr spectrum improve with increased magnetic field strength

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I am struggling to find an equation that illustrates this and a qualitative explanation to go along with it. I presume that the noise remains at the same intensity and somehow the intensity of the genuine signal increases in intensity thus improving the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Homework! ;) The increase is in first approximation quadratic. Hint: One factor has a reason that starts with "B" and ends in "mann".

Comment: The classic paper (>1000 citations): [D. I. Hoult, R. E. Richards: The signal-to-noise ratio of the nuclear magnetic resonance experiment](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2364(76)90233-X) In addition to what Karl has hinted at, I think that the actual voltage in the detection coil is also proportional to the Larmor frequency $\omega_0 = -\gamma B_0$ (Faraday's law), so increasing the static magnetic field $B_0$ improves this too.

Comment: @Karl Ah I think I have it: bigger applied magnetic field leads to bigger energy difference between spin states, hence bigger populations differences, which by the Boltzmann distribution leads to more transitions, hence bigger intensity peaks. Is this right?

Comment: Jup. The other effect is that the induced voltage is proportional to the derivative of the (oscillating, nuclear) magnetic field. Higher frequency, stronger induction. Then you have to take into account the effect on the noise level etc, and it becomes more complicated. See the article by Hould orthocresol linked.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open because of the good discussion in the comments.